# Is there any relation between Decisional Composite Residuosity Assumption and Square roots in elliptic curve groups assumption?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, factoring, hardness-assumptions

We have DCRA and ECSQRT assumptions.

1. ECSQRT: Square roots in elliptic curve groups over Z/nZ
   Definition: Let E(Z/nZ) be the elliptic curve group over Z/nZ. Given a point Q ∈ E(Z/nZ). Compute all points P ∈ E(Z/nZ) such that 2P = Q.
2. DCRA :  DCR: Decisional Composite Residuosity problem
   Definition: Given a composite n and an integer z, decide if z is a n-residue modulo n² or not, namely if there exists y such that z = $y^n(mod n^²)$.

It is known that the Decisional Composite Residuosity Assumption and Square roots in elliptic curve groups assumption are related to factoring problem. I need to know if there is a method or a mathematical theorems that can provide ways to map from DCRA to ECSQRT and if the mapping between the two assumptions is possible.

Comment: Can you formally state what the ECSQRT assumption is?

Comment: Thank you. The question is edited.

Comment: I had thought that ECSQRT (more commonly known as "point halving") was an easy problem. Is $n$ a composite, that is, are you actually trying to perform the operation on a pseudocurve (which isn't actually a group)?